# Avoid that a word be deselected

Tags: c#, select, focus, typing

I'm working in an application which is going to measure the speed of the typing.

I want to select the word that is be writing at that moment. I have this fragment of code in the form load event:

```
string line;

FileStream fs = new FileStream("text.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
StreamReader fr = new StreamReader(fs);

while ((line = fr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    textBox1.AppendText(line);
}

string texto = textBox1.Text;

string[] split = texto.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
textBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
textBox1.SelectionLength = split[0].Length;
```

That works correctly, but when I change the focus to another textbox to begin to type, the selected word disappears.

Is there a way to avoid that from happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the textbox from losing its selection when it loses focus, you can do this (when your form is created).

```
textBox1.HideSelection = false;
```

Refer to the [`TextBoxBase.HideSelection` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.hideselection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the selected text in the text
>   box control remains highlighted when the control loses focus.